# Assigning Repo to module attribute?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I use module attributes to set `Repo` on the fly?
For example, I have `staging` and `production` envs:

```
defmodule Test do
  @repo "staging"

  def repo do
    case @repo do
        "staging" -> alias MyApp.Schools.staging.Repo, as: SRepo
        "production" -> alias MyApp.Schools.prod.Repo, as: SRepo
    end
  end
end
```

if I do: `Test.repo` I get: `Elixir.MyApp.Schools.staging.Repo`
so, why I did not got what I was expecting `MyApp.Schools.staging.Repo` ?

**EDIT**

I also tried just to return the module without alias:

```
def repo do
        case @repo do
            "staging" -> MyApp.Schools.staging.Repo
            "production" -> MyApp.Schools.prod.Repo
        end
      end
```

but, I got `Elixir.MyApp.Schools.staging.Repo`

Comment: This won't work like this. ["import/2, require/2 and alias/2 are called directives and all have lexical scope. This means you can set up aliases inside specific functions and it won’t affect the overall scope."](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#alias/2) Why do you want to do this? Maybe there's another way to solve your problem.

Comment: Please check EDIT bove, what I am trying to do, is to use Repo selectively based on a param sent by request, thus, it should be determined when executing the http request, there is staging DB and production DB, and we need to pick DB based on the sent param.

Comment: maybe what I am trying to do is anti pattern? is having one server  for both staging and production a bad idea?

Comment: But that function doesn't accept any arguments.. you're storing the repo name in the module attribute which can't be modified at runtime. This function can only return one value after it's compiled. Also, what do you mean by you are "getting Elixir.MyApp.Schools.staging.Repo"? `IO.inspect` prints that for the return value?

Comment: yes, IO.puts. By the way, it seems that `iex` adds `Elixir` as a prefix to all modules when I do `IO.puts` .. I just tried `IO.puts Test` and I got Elixir.Test

Comment: Yes, `IO.puts` prints the raw value of atoms while `IO.inspect` prints it in the way we type the value in Elixir. About the question: why don't you have a function like `def repo("staging"), do: MyApp.Schools.Staging.Repo; def repo("production"), do: MyApp.Schools.Production.Repo`? Module attributes cannot be modified but you want to be able to select a repo per request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to switch the repo based on a value in the params received by controller functions (instead of the more common way of running a separate instance of the app, one with `MyApp.Repo` pointing to staging and one pointing to production), you can create a function that just returns the appropriate Repo module based on the params, and then call functions on the returned value.

```
defmodule MyApp do
  def repo("staging"), do: MyApp.Staging.Repo
  def repo("production"), do: MyApp.Production.Repo
end

defmodule MyApp.PostController do
  ...
  # env can be "staging" or "production"
  def index(conn, %{"env" => env}) do
    repo = MyApp.repo(env)
    render conn, "index.html", posts: repo.all(Post)
  end
end
```